# Cassandra com.datastax.driver open session to keyspace that might not exists

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, java

I am working on project that uses cassandra as a NoSql database. I am trying to setup my test framework to be able to work with an arbitrary keyspace to avoid collisions between different tests running at the same time.

I would like to be able to create session against keyspace that might not exists. Essentially what I want is to first check if it exists and if not to create it, and then to connect.

It seems that the Api has catch 22 because in order I to execute command (that could create keyspace) I already have to have connection to an existing keyspace.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look through the tutorials in the DataStax documentation, and you should be able to come up with a way to do this.  The first part illustrates how to [connect to the database cluster](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientCreate_t.html).  It walks you through coming up with a simple `connect` method that is not specific to a keyspace.

```
private Cluster cluster;

public void connect(String node) {
   cluster = Cluster.builder()
         .addContactPoint(node)
         .build();
}
```

The next part discusses how to [use a `session` object to execute CQL statements](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientAddSession_t.html).  You could probably query the `schema_keyspaces` table to see if the keyspace in question exists with something like this:

```
Session session = cluster.connect();
ResultSet results = session.execute("SELECT * FROM system.schema_keyspaces " +
    "WHERE keyspace_name = 'myKeyspaceNameGoesHere';");
```

The tutorial then shows specifically how to create a new keyspace via the Java Driver.

```
session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE myKeyspaceNameGoesHere WITH replication " + 
      "= {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':3};");
```

Note that I have pulled the code here from the examples in the docs.  You will want to substitute your own keyspace name, replication strategy and factor.

Comment: This is very helpful, however, the links are dead.

Comment: @carl_platt Fixed.  Thanks for letting me know!